# libtool installed but not found by buildconf

Tags: cross-compilation, configure

I'm trying to cross-compile Apache httpd for ARM.
Here what I did:

```
$ sudo apt install libtool
$ git clone https://github.com/apache/httpd.git
$ cd httpd
$ svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk srclib/apr
$ ./buildconf
```

The output is:

```
found apr source: srclib/apr
rebuilding srclib/apr/configure
buildconf: checking installation...
buildconf: python version 3.5.6 (ok)
buildconf: autoconf version 2.69 (ok)
buildconf: libtool not found.
           You need libtool version 1.4 or newer installed
           to build APR from SVN.
./buildconf failed for apr
```

But `libtool` is installed:

```
$ sudo apt install libtool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libtool is already the newest version (2.4.6-0.1).
```

Comment: What were your next steps to build it for ARM ? I need to do the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/bin/libtool` is provided by the package `libtool-bin` → File search : https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=usr%2Fbin%2Flibtool

Package search : https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libtool-bin&searchon=names

```
$ sudo apt install libtool-bin
```